# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que mi sitio sea puesto en un iframe?

Tags: php, html

¿Como puedo evitar que mi sitio sea puesto en un `<iframe>` y cómo puedo permitir que sólo un sitio pueda ponerlo en él?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes comprobar si una página está dentro de un `<iframe>` o no probando si `window.self` (ventana o marco actual) y `window.top` (ventana o marco padre) es el mismo:

```js
try {
  console.log('Estamos en iframe: ', window.self !== window.top);
  console.log('Si nos lo permite CORS, podemos ver la URL:',
    window.top.location);
} catch (e) {
  /* Las políticas "same origin" impiden que accedamos a window.top */
  console.log('Estamos en iframe');
}
```

Si no se cumplen las políticas de [mismo origen (same origin)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica) entonces no podremos comprobar la URL de la página padre, será imposible dar acceso a unas páginas sí y otras no si no lo acceso haciendo uso de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Las políticas de mismo origen se cumplen si incluyes una página dentro de otra si:

> Dos páginas tienen el mismo origen si el protocolo, puerto (si es especificado) y host son los mismo para ambas páginas. Verá esto a veces referido como la tupla esquema/host/puerto" (donde una "tupla" es un conjunto de tres componentes que juntos forman un todo).
>
> La siguiente tabla muestra ejemplos de comparaciones de origenes para la URL `http://store.company.com/dir/page.html`:
>
> - http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html - **Éxito**
> - http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html - **Éxito**
> - https://store.company.com/secure.html - **Fallo** (diferente protocolo)
> - http://store.company.com:81/dir/etc.html - **Fallo** (diferente puerto)
> - http://news.company.com/dir/other.html - **Fallo** (diferente host)

Para implementar CORS en PHP necesitas hacer uso de la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` tal y como se muestra en este ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* Aquí comprobamos HTTP_REFERER para ver si permitimos o no el iframe */
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === 'http://urlpermitida/exacta.html') {
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://urlpermitida');
}
/* Resto del código de la página */
```